# Invalid apache 200 response

Tags: log-files, apache2

I have the following logs on my apache2.

```
61.157.96.193 - - [10/Aug/2016:12:09:47 +0200] "GET http://50.117.47.67:43530/?rands=_11744130666812773703498720 HTTP/1.1" 200 11359 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)"
104.216.4.237 - - [02/Sep/2016:01:30:05 +0200] "GET http://104.216.4.237:8653/?rands=_130685931643406872390480 HTTP/1.1" 200 11359 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)"
```

This should return a 404 response?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have mod_proxy enabled which allows the request to succeed. I'd disable the module if you don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

If your Apache server is not configured to behave as a proxy it is going to ignore the protocol and hostname part of the `GET` request. Thus it will behave as if the client had requested:

```
/?rands=_11744130666812773703498720
```

The `?` character indicates that the rest of the URL is parameters. Thus it should only produce a 404 code if there is no `/` on your server. Assuming `/` on your server does not look for a `rands` parameter the response will be the same as if the client had sent this request:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
```